# BZ of hexagonal unit cell

Tags: solid-state-physics

I plotted all the points of the BZ of the hexagonal unit cell. What I want to be sure of is whether all K-points (here K1,K2,K3,etc..) are equidistant to the zone center Gamma? The coordinates which I have used are: 
K1( 0.333,-0.667)
K2(0.667,-0.333)
K3(0.333,0.333)
K4(-0.333,0.667)
...

Without calculating the distances between Gamma and K1 or K2, it is obvious that these points are equidistant w.r.t. point Gamma. But If I calculate the distance between K3-Gamma, it gives of course a different value. 
My question is: Should it be like this or are the coordinates which I am using wrong? I also attached a file where all points are plotted.

[image]

Thank you in advance! I really appreciate any help!

Best wishes,
DaveS

Comment: Hint: if the euclidean distance is at all relevant to the plot, and you do not have extremely good reasons to do otherwise, then plotting with a distorted aspect ratio (i.e. different scales on the different axes) amounts to producing a misleading plot and should *never* be done.

Comment: I think, I know my mistake or at least I just wanted to be sure about that. I agree with you.  It´s a matter of presentation. If I present the square-lattice in a distorted way ("sheared-one" not like now as a 2D-plot) then I think I will take this aspect-ratio into account and it should give me the right solution. In this sense, I would say that all K-points are equidistant to the zone center Gamma in the case of a symmetric hexagon. I just posted the question too fast before thinking about that properly...

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a bit more information about the problem? If the lattice is a symmetric hexagon, then the BZ should be as well. Take graphene for example. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.0127.pdf

If your lattice is symmetric, perhaps there is a basis element that breaks the symmetry?

A possible mistake is that the usual basis vector definitions have different lengths, due to the symmetry of the problem (picture). [image: 1]

Thus in the case of the paper, the equations are   [image: 2]   or [image: 3].

Comment: Thanks for the paper, I was reading that already yesterday. It should be a symmetric one so I guess I only have to change my point of view when looking at the 2D-plot just like @emilio-pisanty pointed out. This is what I wanted to be sure about, thanks for you both!